# Hibernate inject class type

Tags: java, hibernate

Assuming I have a super class `SuperEntity` and that I have subclasses named `EntityOne` and `EntityTwo` (both of which have their table in the database)

Is this a good idea? Will hibernate narrow down the search for me to only one entity (table) ?

```
session.createQuery("from " + className + " a where...")
```

So if I pass the in the instance type, will hibernate query only the one table I parametrized? so instead of doing this :

```
session.createQuery("from SuperEntity a where...")
```

Which should in theory query both tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using class name from template argument is standard practice. Google for 'abstract hibernate dao'.
Example: http://yanuar7199.wordpress.com/2013/03/30/hibernate-generic-dao-for-generic-purpose/